# Include file.h not working in android studio in c programming (using SDL2)

Tags: android, c, android-studio, include, linker-errors

I'm actually developing a C app on Android Studio using the SDL 2, a C graphic library. But the problem doesn't come from the library itself but from the `#include` of my own files.

I created source files in which I put my functions, I associated to them header files with the declarations of the functions. But when I call the functions in my main source file, I get the error:
`error: undefined reference to 'draw_render_rectangle'` for example.
It doesn't work for any of my files or functions. But it works for the SDL.

So I try to `#include`.
Main source file "main_graphics.c":

```
#include "main_graphics.h"
void disp_main_menu(int selected) {
    POINT A, B;
    A.x = 0;
    A.y = 0;
    B.x = WIDTH;
    B.y = HEIGHT;
    draw_render_rectangle(A, B, 70, 70, 70);
}
```

Main header file "main_graphics.h":

```
#ifndef ANDROID_GAME_MAIN_GRAPHICS_H
#define ANDROID_GAME_MAIN_GRAPHICS_H


#include "../SDL2/include/SDL.h"
#include "../SDL2/include/SDL.h"
#include "../SDL2_ttf/SDL_ttf.h"
#include "../SDL2_image/SDL_image.h"
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "graphics_mobile.h"
int WIDTH = 1080;
int HEIGHT = 1920;

void disp_main_menu(int selected);

#endif //ANDROID_GAME_MAIN_GRAPHICS_H
```

"graphics_mobile.c" :

```
#include "graphics_mobile.h"

typedef struct point {int x,y;} POINT;

void draw_render_rectangle(POINT p1, POINT p2, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b)
{
    SDL_Rect rectangle;
    int xmin, xmax;
    int ymin, ymax;
    int i,j;

    if (p1.x < p2.x) {xmin=p1.x; xmax=p2.x;} else{xmin=p2.x; xmax=p1.x;}
    if (p1.y < p2.y) {ymin=p1.y; ymax=p2.y;} else{ymin=p2.y; ymax=p1.y;}

    rectangle.x = xmin;
    rectangle.y = HEIGHT - (ymax-ymin) - ymin;
    rectangle.w = xmax-xmin;
    rectangle.h = ymax-ymin;
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, texture);
    SDL_RenderDrawRect(renderer,&rectangle);
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, r, g, b, 0x00);
    SDL_RenderFillRect(renderer, &rectangle);
    SDL_SetRenderTarget(renderer, NULL);
    SDL_RenderCopy(renderer, texture, NULL, NULL);
}
```

"graphics_mobile.h"

```
#ifndef ANDROID_GAME_GRAPHICS_MOBILE_H
#define ANDROID_GAME_GRAPHICS_MOBILE_H
#include "main_graphics.h"

typedef struct point {int x,y;} POINT;

void draw_render_rectangle(POINT p1, POINT p2, Uint8 r, Uint8 g, Uint8 b);

#endif //ANDROID_GAME_GRAPHICS_MOBILE_H
```

One thing that is weird is that the autocompletion is working, when I type the function, it actually recognize it and tells me in the little window of the autocompletion that it is defined in "graphics_mobile.h".

Can the problem come from the compilator?
I tried ndk-bundle_10e and ndk-bundle_16b and I get the same error.

Comment: "*error: undefined reference to 'draw_render_rectangle'*" is a linker error. It is not a compile error. The linker seems to be missing the object compiled out of  `graphics_mobile.c`. It might be called `graphics_mobile.o` or `graphics_mobile.obj` or alike.

Comment: How do you compile and link the code?

Comment: I don't really know, it's a compiler from android studio and the linker I don't know either what it is

Answer (score 0):

So I did some tests and I got a working code :

you have to put in "graphics_mobile.h":

```
#ifndef ANDROID_GAME_GRAPHICS_MOBILE_H
#define ANDROID_GAME_GRAPHICS_MOBILE_H
#include "main_graphics.h"
#include "graphics_mobile.c"

#endif //ANDROID_GAME_GRAPHICS_MOBILE_H
```

and remove the declarations of the functions

Comment: Nono, do not do this. Including a .c file into another .c file might work, but definitely is not the way this **linker** issue should be worked around. Imagine you had dozens or hundreds of .c files. ...

Comment: Yes I agree with you this code is not what should be done but that's the only thing that works for now for me on android studio